# Handling CodeIgniter Errors When View Loads Within a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, codeigniter-3

I have a CodeIgniter application.  In one module, the setup is a list page that shows all current records, with a button to add a new record and a button to edit an existing record.

The add and edit actions each have different views.

I have a single blank Bootstrap-3 modal saved as a separate view (modal.php).  When either the add or edit buttons are clicked, the modal pops up as an overlay on the list page. I have added data attributes to the links for the add and edit buttons that help build out the modal headers and content.

Example:
When the "add" button is clicked, the title and button text for the modal mined from the data attributes, and the view file for the add action is loaded as the modal body.

The "add" button link on the list page:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('client/add'); ?>" class="btn btn-success ls-modal" data-title="Add New Client" data-btn_txt="Add" data-mode="add">Add</a>
```

The Jquery that loads the views/client/add.php file into the modal:

```
$('.ls-modal').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var title = $(this).data('title');
var btn_txt = $(this).data('btn_txt');
var mode = $(this).data('mode');

$('#modal_title').html(title);
$("#client-sbmt").html(btn_txt);
$('#client_form_mode').val(mode);

$('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));
```

});

This all works great.  The problem however is when I encounter an error in the form.  I use CodeIgniter's set_rules() in the form helper to set up some validation rules. If the validation fails, then I lose the modal window that overlays the list page.  Instead, the actual view loads into the tab and shows the form errors.

Here's what the add method in the controller looks like:

```
public function add()
{   
    //If form submitted
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //Form validation
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_name','Client Name','required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone','phone','min_length[7]');

    //if validated
    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)     
    {   
        $phone = $this->input->post('phone1');
        $phone .= $this->input->post('phone2');
        $phone .= $this->input->post('phone3');

        $params = array(
            'client_name' => $this->input->post('client_name'),
            'client_code' => $this->input->post('client_code'),
            'address1' => $this->input->post('address1'),
            'address2' => $this->input->post('address2'),
            'city' => $this->input->post('city'),
            'postal' => $this->input->post('postal'),
            'state' => $this->input->post('state'),
            'country' => strtoupper($this->input->post('country')),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'phone_cc' => $this->input->post('phone_cc'),
            'phone' => $phone,
            'phone_ext' => $this->input->post('phone_ext'),
            'po_prefix' => $this->input->post('po_prefix'),
            'logo' => $this->input->post('logo')
        );

        $client_id = $this->Client_model->add_client($params);
        //redirect('client/index');
    }

}

//Load View            
$data['_view'] = 'client/modal_add';
$this->load->view('layouts/main',$data);
```

}

How can I ensure that even if the validation errors are present, the form remains within a modal on the list page?

Comment: use `form_error();` to show the individual input error

Comment: @pradeep yes, I am ready using form_error on the view page to echo out the errors.  However, that does not the modal closing and having the view itself take over in the window in the presence of an error.